# Create Custom Action for Ribbon in SharePoint hosted Add in

Tags: 2013, ribbon, sharepoint-addin

I am following the instructions in http://sharepointinterface.com/2013/01/22/custom-ribbon-button-image-limitations-with-sharepoint-2013-apps/ (and other walk through pages) both on my on premise DEV site and on a new 365 DEV site.
In both cases I get no errors but there is no added ribbon item.

Could it be that this functionality was eliminated in the newer versions?
Could it be I am missing a step?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Custom actions should still be around. On top of this, you only have to follow the very first steps of that article to see a new button in the ribbon (till "Deploying the App that contains the custom action markup shown above..."). So, the main step is only about copy/pasting the XML block.

Can you show us what you have in your solution and your element.xml file?
Do you look for your new button at the right location (i.e. in the "Library" tab of any doc lib of your **host web**)?

Comment: Can you elaborate on what was wrong? Im facing here the same situation